# Catching channel faults within service methods?

Tags: c#, wcf, client, fault

Is it possible, within a WCF service method, to catch a client's channel fault? Currently, I'm only able to catch channel faults through:

```
OperationContext.Current.Channel.Faulted += new EventHandler(Channel_Faulted);
```

However, I'd like the service method to be interrupted (i.e. throw an exception) if the response cannot be delivered to client. Currently, my service continues sending the response to client without throwing anything although the channel is faulted (according to the Faulted event).

Additional Note: I'm using reliable sessions with netTcpBinding, but still when the service sends the response and there is no client, I don't get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want your service to throw an exception when there is no client?

WCF is in essence a messaging system, just like our postal system.  If you as a client send me a letter, I (the service) will respond to your address.  I just assume that you are still living there and that you'll be still be alive to read my response.

Even if I see on the evening news that you got ran over by a truck (let's hope not ;-)) while I'm writing my response.  Why would I need to yell 'hey I can't send my response to that guy!'?  There would be no one to listen to me.  And you don't care anymore...

Reliable sessions just add an extra acknowledgement step in between.  You send me the letter, I respond with 'I got your letter, I'll respond to it later'.  If you don't get that reply, you just resend your original letter and I'll notice that you send me the same letter again.  So I'll respond again.  Same story for the response.  If I don't get your 'I got your response' message, I'll try to respond again, and again, and again.  Until I finally give up...  either because I watched the evening news or I'm getting tired of writing the same letter again.  But the end result is the same.  I have still no one to yell to, because you are not listening to me anymore...

The story is different in duplex bindings.  Then the communication is ended when the server gets the message.  And then the roles become reversed (server becomes client and client becomes server).  The server (now client) sends a new communication on the return channel to the client (now server).  And because that call is triggered by a method call, that method call will fail with an exception on the server side.